# What is 'admiralty' as an abstract noun?

Tags: meaning

I've looked it up and found:

- Admiralty => office of the Admiralty & Marine Affairs -- an institution under various names in England.
- Admiralty => a building and department.
- Admiralty => court dealing with maritime law.

But this all started when I ran into this, the final verse of Rudyard Kipling's "Song of the Dead"

> We must feed our sea for a thousand years,
>   For that is our doom and pride,
>   As it was when they sailed with the ~Golden Hind~,
>   Or the wreck that struck last tide --
>   Or the wreck that lies on the spouting reef
>   Where the ghastly blue-lights flare.
>   If blood be the price of **admiralty**,
>   If blood be the price of **admiralty**,
>   If blood be the price of **admiralty**,
>   Lord God, we ha' bought it fair!

In this context, I don't understand what Kipling means by 'admiralty'

Enlightenment, please.

One good answer refers to the Oxford Phrase dictionary for "Price of Admiralty" and says "The cost of maintaining command of the seas." and refers to Kipling's poem.

Is Kipling's use of "admiralty" poetic license? Are there any other examples of its use as an abstract noun?

Comment: Plus 1 for reading Kipling and asking a question about him in an English Learner forum.

Comment: @puppetsock — This is NOT an English Learner forum. Please read the Tour which makes that clear. English Language Learners is the SE site for learners.

Comment: Too late to edit.  OK  then.  gs/learner/language/

Comment: If you are learning English, a good exercise would be to correct the use of the apostrophe in your final paragraph. There is one apostrophe missing, and one that shouldn’t be there. If you cannot see them, consult one of the numerous articles on the topic you can find on the Internet.

Answer (score 8):

> **price of admiralty**
>
> The cost of maintaining command of the seas, often with reference to Kipling's line, "If blood be the price of admiralty Good God, we ha' paid in full" ('Song of the English', 1893).

<sub>Source: [The Oxford Dictionary of Phrase and Fable](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095351992)</sub>

In this context, "admiralty" refers to naval power (or specifically, the [Royal Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy)).

Comment: Undoubtedly it does. An admiral is a senior naval officer, The Admiralty was the British government department dealing with naval affairs (now part of the Ministry of Defence), so Kipling is using the word to mean 'command of the seas'.

Comment: I'd like to see more examples than Kipling, and have edited my question accordingly.  Thanks to @Flux.

Comment: @KateBunting But I think it's a sense unique to Kipling. The OED has no entry for it.

Comment: @WS2 It's disgusting, expecting people to accept new senses and words just because we're a famous author. We should resist this forcibly, every last man, woman and hobbit of us.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All I am saying is that I think it is unique to Kipling. But I am perfectly willing to stand corrected if anyone proves otherwise.

Comment: @WS2 I didn't think I needed to add the :). _Hobbit_???